# Continuity of map from Cantor set to $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, continuity, cantor-set

$K$ : Cantor set

$\phi$ : $K \to [0,1]$, given by $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2\epsilon_k}{3^k} \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\epsilon_k}{2^k} \ (\epsilon_k=0,1)$

I want to prove that $\phi$ is continuous on $K$.

Let $\epsilon >0.$

I have to prove

$\exists \delta>0,  |x-a|<\delta \ (a\in K)\Rightarrow |\phi (x)-\phi (a)|< \epsilon.$

I have to decide $\delta= \cdots$,

and I can write $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2\epsilon_k}{3^k}, a=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2\epsilon'_k}{3^k}$ and when $|x-a|<\delta$,

\begin{align}
|\phi (x)-\phi (a)|
&=\left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\epsilon_k}{2^k} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\epsilon'_k}{2^k} \right| \\
&= \left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\epsilon_k-\epsilon'_k}{2^k}  \right|\\
&\leqq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left| \dfrac{\epsilon_k-\epsilon'_k}{2^k} \right|
\end{align}

and I want to use $|x-a|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\epsilon_k-\epsilon'_k}{3^k}\right|<\delta.$

I have no idea about how I have to determine $\delta$ and how I have to evaluate $|\phi (x)-\phi (a)|$.

I would like you to give me some ideas.

Comment: This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2751213/121671)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $k$ is the first position at which $\epsilon_k$ and $\epsilon'_k$ differ. You can prove that $|x-y| \ge \frac{1}{3^k}$ and that $\left| \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\epsilon_k}{2^k} - \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\epsilon'_k}{2^k} \right| \le 2^{-k+1}$